# minko bone animation with hardware support causes Error #3659: AGAL validation failed

Tags: registry, constants, vertices, agal, minko

I updated minko as3 code to run on standard profile instead of baseline and i have a mesh with animations that i know for a fact, has 185 vertices constants, maximum allowed amount is 250 on standard, but i keep getting [trace] Error: Error #3659: AGAL validation failed: Constant register index out of bounds for source operand 1 at token 1 of vertex program.

i have zero knowledge about how agal works, but i do understand minko. Could anyone please point me in the right direction what to change? I have already adjusted minko Profile.as class and locations where its used, thats how i was able to zero in on exact amount of vertice constants in registry (185)

Answer (score 2):

Hardware animations require more computations and more registers.

It looks like the standard has less registers. But the Minko AS3 shader doesn't know that. The limitations taken into account are enforced here:

https://github.com/aerys/minko-as3/blob/master/src/aerys/minko/render/shader/compiler/register/RegisterLimit.as

They probably fit with the baseline profile. I'm not sure if changing them will actually help you, because the problem might just be that the AGAL standard profile simply doesn't have enough constant registers...

If you're using `SkinningMethod.HARDWARE_MATRIX`, you should consider using `SkinningMethod.HARDWARE_DUAL_QUATERNION` instead.

You could also set the `skinningMaxInfluences` property of your mesh to something lower. It should definitely try to use a more memory savy shader code (see https://github.com/aerys/minko-as3/blob/master/src/aerys/minko/render/shader/part/animation/SkinningShaderPart.as for the implementation details).

Comment: RegisterLimit class and its constants have zero usages, i found that https://github.com/aerys/minko-as3/blob/726d0d404c40315a62599c434e8105ec77e5d01d/src/aerys/minko/render/Profile.as now contains the limits, and changing them actually affects the location of where the error is thrown (shader compiler or Context3D) also http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2014/09/stage3d-standard-profile.html register sizes are increased on every registry, the problematic vertex constants register is now 250 instead of 128, unless im reading something wrong. Tried using dual quaternion and distortions appear.